# Electron: Hide Taskbar/Dock Icon - Linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, electron

one could hide the app's taskbar icon on Windows using `skipTaskbar` to true and on Mac using `app.dock.hide()`. How would you achieve the same (not show an icon in the dock) on Linux? (Both of them do not work for me on Linux)

Answer (score 0):

using  `"electron": "13.6.3",` and tested on `Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS`

This is how I achieved hiding the dock icon on linux by simply hiding the `BrowswerWindow` window

```js
import {BrowserWindow} from 'electron';

let mainWindow: BrowserWindow | null = null;

mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

const hideDock = () => {
if(process.platform === "linux"){
      mainWindow?.hide() //This is enough to hide the dock icon on `linux`
    }
}
```

the [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#event-hide) doesn't mention that it hides the dock icon on linux tho.